# How do I get a function to iterate through a string and replace the first character of a string, second, etc?

Tags: python, encryption, python-3.x, while-loop, iteration

I'm attempting to create a Baconian cipher encryption program that reads input for a message, a fake message, and an integer key, and then outputs the fake message shifted through a Caesar cipher encryption program, but with spaces and symbols of the Baconian cipher representing the bold and normal font, or what I'm using as 'A' and 'B'.

Here's what I have so far. It's mostly completed, but I can't get the output to cycle through the characters in the string that is encrypted with the Caesar cipher, instead it just uses the first character. I'm pretty positive it's something idiotic, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions? :

```
def main():
    myBaconianMessage = input('Please input Bacon cipher message.')
    myBaconianMessage = myBaconianMessage.split()
    myCaesarMessage = input('Please input fake message to be encrypted.')
    myCaesarKey = int(input('Please input integer key.'))
    clues_A = {'A':'AAAAA'}
    clues_B = {'B':'AAAAB'}
    clues = {'a':'AAAAA', 'b':'AAAAB', 'c':'AAABA', 'd':'AAABB', 'e':'AABAA',
             'f':'AABAB', 'g':'AABBA', 'h':'AABBB', 'i':'ABAAA', 'j':'ABAAA',
             'k':'ABAAB', 'l':'ABABA', 'm':'ABABB', 'n':'ABBAA', 'o':'ABBAB',
             'p':'ABBBA', 'q':'ABBBB', 'r':'BAAAA', 's':'BAAAB', 't':'BAABA',
             'u':'BAABB', 'v':'BAABB', 'w':'BABAA', 'x':'BABAB', 'y':'BABBA',
             'z':'BABBB', 'C':'AAABA', 'D':'AAABB', 'E':'AABAA', 'F':'AABAB',
             'G':'AABBA', 'H':'AABBB', 'I':'ABAAA', 'J':'ABAAA', 'K':'ABAAB',
             'L':'ABABA', 'M':'ABABB', 'N':'ABBAA', 'O':'ABBAB', 'P':'ABBBA',
             'Q':'ABBBB', 'R':'BAAAA', 'S':'BAAAB', 'T':'BAABA', 'U':'BAABB',
             'V':'BAABB', 'W':'BABAA', 'X':'BABAB', 'Y':'BABBA', 'Z':'BABBB'}


    def decrypter():
        translated = myBaconianMessage[:]
        for i, word in enumerate(translated):
            for key in clues_A:
                translated[i] = translated[i].replace(key, clues_A.get(key))
            for key in clues_B:
                translated[i] = translated[i].replace(key, clues_B.get(key))
            for key in clues:
                translated[i] = translated[i].replace(key, clues.get(key))
        encryptedMessage = ''.join(translated)
        return encryptedMessage


    def caesarPortion():
        myCaesarMode = 'encrypt'
        alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        caesarMessage = ''
        newCaesarMessage = myCaesarMessage.lower()
        for symbol in newCaesarMessage:
            if symbol in alphabet:
                num = alphabet.find(symbol)
                if myCaesarMode == 'encrypt':
                    num = num + myCaesarKey
                elif myCaesarMode == 'decrypt':
                    num = num - myCaesarKey
                if num >= len(alphabet):
                    num = num - len(alphabet)
                elif num < 0:
                    num = num + len(alphabet)
                caesarMessage = caesarMessage + alphabet[num]
        else:
            caesarMessage = caesarMessage + symbol
        thisCaesarMessage = ''.join(caesarMessage)
        return thisCaesarMessage


    def doubleEncrypted():
        caesar = caesarPortion()
        listCaesar = list(caesar)
        translate = decrypter()
        listTranslate = translate.split()
        for char in range(len(listCaesar) - 1):
            i = 0
            while i <= len(listCaesar):
                i += 1
                set = {'A':listCaesar[i], 'B':' '}
                for symbol in listTranslate:
                    for x, word in enumerate(listTranslate):
                        for key in set:
                            listTranslate[x] = listTranslate[x].replace(key,  ''.join(str(set.get(key))))
    return listTranslate

    if len(myBaconianMessage) >= 1:
        print(''.join(doubleEncrypted()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I know that it's something in doubleEncrypted() that's the problem, probably the while loop or set or range, and I know the code really isn't elegant at all, but I'm a n00b and I'm just trying to figure out how things work. I'd really, really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Hi, is your snippet indentation is correct, all the functions are inside main ? or if yes why you write that way.

Comment: Yeah, it seemed that was the only way to get main() to continue on to execute caesarPortion()...pretty sure there's a different, correct way to do it, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem is inside `doubleEncrypted` function with the while loop:

```
# this while loop will loop from `i` is incremented before indexing 
while i <= len(listCaesar):
```

Here is an example snippet:

```
>>> listCaesar = 'MyName'
>>> len(listCaesar)
6
>>> range(6 - 1)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for char in range(6 - 1):
...     i = 0
...     while i <= 6:
...         i += 1
...         print i, listCaesar[i]
...
1 y
2 N
3 a
4 m
5 e
6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
>>>
```

In the above example, `i` is incrementing before indexing, so when it reach 6, the list index is out of range.

So, you can fix that by adding `i += 1` after listCaesar indexing. Even I feel this is the right way because you are incrementing `i` after indexing, not before.

```
>>> for char in range(6 - 1):
...     i = 0
...     while i < 6:       # while i <=5:
...         print i, listCaesar[i]
...         i += 1
...
0 M
1 y
2 N
3 a
4 m
```

Comment: I did that, but now I keep getting error: IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: which one you did, can you print i, listCaesar[i] just before the while loop ? and i want to see the last i, compare to the length of listCaesar

Comment: I just took the i += 1 and put it after set = {...etc, because I need it to operate in my code the way I want it to...is that wrong?

Comment: see the problem, is you are trying to index a list which is outside the range means for example you have a list of size = 4, List = [1,2,3,4], List[3] = 4, as List index start from 0, so if you increment i before indexing, it will always goes outside the list size. as you are looping on the range of the list length - 1.

Comment: So, if you put i += 1 after set, then change the while loop to `<` not  `<=`

Comment: And i am not asking you to change the way you solve it, we are here trying to fix a problem. if we fixed the problem, you will surely change it even i din't request you to change it, because you want to fix your problem anyway:)

Comment: I really appreciate your help...it got rid of the error, but it's still only printing the first character in the string. Like, for example, I have the string 'BAABAAABBBABAAABAAAB.', and the string 'bpqaqainismumaaiom.' I want the output to be ' bp qaq   a ini mum .' instead of ' bb bbb   b bbb bbb .', which is the current output.

Comment: what is the integer key you used ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 7 years late, but this is a Baconian that works great:
It encodes and decodes:

```
What = int(input("Would you like to... 1. Encode, or 2. Decode? "))

if What == 1:
  Input = str(input("")).upper()
  BaconianTable = {
    "A": "AAAAA ",
    "B": "AAAAB ",
    "C": "AAABA ",
    "D": "AAABB ",
    "E": "AABAA ",
    "F": "AABAB ",
    "G": "AABBA ",
    "H": "AABBB ",
    "I": "ABAAA ",
    "J": "ABAAA ",
    "K": "ABAAB ",
    "L": "ABABA ",
    "M": "ABABB ",
    "N": "ABBAA ",
    "O": "ABBAB ",
    "P": "ABBBA ",
    "Q": "ABBBB ",
    "R": "BAAAA ",
    "S": "BAAAB ",
    "T": "BAABA ",
    "U": "BAABB ",
    "V": "BAABB ",
    "W": "BABAA ",
    "X": "BABAB ",
    "Y": "BABBA ",
    "Z": "BABBB ",
    " ": " ",
    ".": ".",
    ",": ",",
    "!": "!",
    "?": "?"
  }

  X = list(Input)
  Answer = ""
  Y = 0
  for i in range(len(Input)):
    Answer = Answer + str(BaconianTable[X[Y]])
    Y += 1
  print(Answer)
elif What == 2:
  Input = str(input("")).upper()
  Input = Input.replace("AAAAA", "a")
  Input = Input.replace("AAAAB", "b")
  Input = Input.replace("AAABA", "c")
  Input = Input.replace("AAABB", "d")
  Input = Input.replace("AABAA", "e")
  Input = Input.replace("AABAB", "f")
  Input = Input.replace("AABBA", "g")
  Input = Input.replace("AABBB", "H")
  Input = Input.replace("ABAAA", "|i (or) j|")
  Input = Input.replace("ABAAB", "k")
  Input = Input.replace("ABABA", "l")
  Input = Input.replace("ABABB", "m")
  Input = Input.replace("ABBAA", "n")
  Input = Input.replace("ABBAB", "o")
  Input = Input.replace("ABBBA", "p")
  Input = Input.replace("ABBBB", "q")
  Input = Input.replace("BAAAA", "r")
  Input = Input.replace("BAAAB", "s")
  Input = Input.replace("BAABA", "t")
  Input = Input.replace("BAABB", "|u (or) v|")
  Input = Input.replace("BABAA", "w")
  Input = Input.replace("BABAB", "x")
  Input = Input.replace("BABBA", "y")
  Input = Input.replace("BABBB", "z")
  Input = Input.replace("  ", "+")
  Input = Input.replace(" ", "")
  Input = Input.replace("+", " ")    
  print(Input.capitalize())
```